# How to setup gmaps.js in a basic html skeleton

Tags: jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

everyone

I have some trouble setting up gmaps in a little project.

> Take note that the api keys aren't correctly entered.

I just copied one of their examples in their documentations.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZWTTkguiQpNFtckx_x_x_x_xI&libraries=places"
    async defer></script>
    <!-- <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script> -->
    <script src="./js/gmaps.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/map.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        $(function(){
            map = new GMaps({
                el: '#map',
                lat: -12.043333,
                lng: -77.028333,
                zoomControl : true,
                zoomControlOpt: {
                    style : 'SMALL',
                    position: 'TOP_LEFT'
                },
                panControl : false,
                streetViewControl : false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                overviewMapControl: false
            }); 
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        body { 
            font-family : 'Helvetica Neue','arial',sans-serif;
            font-size : 15px;
        }

        #map {
            height :100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-2x mb-2" style="font-size: 20px;">
            Mapp
        </h1>

        <h3>How it works ?</h3>

    <!-- insert map -->
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to open the google chrome developer tools I have an error that says:

> Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript
>   library https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.

Comment: You can't comment out `<script>` tags

Comment: Still can't display the map @geocodezip

Answer (score 2):

Issues:

- There is a typo in the posted HTML (missing the closing `</div>` for the `<div class="container">`).
- The CSS won't work for percentage sizing, it needs to define the size of the containing element (can be done by defining `html, body { height: 100%; }`, see the related question: [Responsive Google Maps v3 - Cannot get 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866519/responsive-google-maps-v3-cannot-get-100-height)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z2hqjypt/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
$(function() {
  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
      style: 'SMALL',
      position: 'TOP_LEFT'
    },
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    overviewMapControl: false
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  height: 70%;
}

html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/hpneo/gmaps@master/gmaps.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-2x mb-2" style="font-size: 20px;">
    Mapp
  </h1>

  <h3>How it works ?</h3>

  <!-- insert map -->
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was able to set it up and I saw the map but I still get a Oops something went wrong error..

Comment: This error is in my console : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at common.js:71
    at Object._.jd (js?key=AIzaSyCZWTTkguiQpNFtckZZ5lpJLvVvMcI:58)
    at a (common.js:71)
    at Ap (common.js:71)
    at common.js:77
    at rp.i (common.js:151)
    at Object.c [as _1era5m] (common.js:69)
    at QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2004%2F&3sAIzaSyCZWTTkguiQpNFtckZZ5lpJLvVvMc0hsmI&7su8j5qn&10e1&callback=_xdc_._1era5m&key=AIzaSyCZWTTkguiQpNFtckZZ5lpJLvVvMc0hsmI&token=21061:1`

Comment: If it works in the fiddle and code snippet, but fails on your website (or local machine), then it is probably a problem with the key.  Did you change the key? Is your key associated with a billing account and/or restricted?  Looking at the error message it looks like there are multiple different keys in the message.

Comment: On my domain, with my key [it works](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20191017.html)

Comment: On my domain, with the key from the fiddle (Google's key, which isn't enabled for my domain) [it gives the same error you see](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20191017googleKey.html)

Comment: I think I already enabled it in the Maps because I already see the green checkmark that says API enabled

Answer (score 0):

I belie that the example Google API KEY is restricted for his domain and we cannot us it.
The code works when I swap the key for mine. Make sure the key has all the API's the gmaps.js is using enabled for your API KEY (I enabled all as just in case. Will update KEY permissions for deployment)